# How can I get the right type from a FromBody model which is inherits?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

There are several different XML incomings from the post of the body. All of the XMLS are almost the same so I add a baseclass first and others XMLS inherits from the baseclass.

Here is the model:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(TextMsg))]
[XmlRoot("xml")]        
public class BaseClass
{
    public string ToUserName { get; set; }
    public string FromUserName { get; set; }
    public string CreateTime { get; set; }
    public string MsgType { get; set; }            
}        
[XmlRoot("xml")]        
public class TextMsg : BaseClass
{
    public TextMsg()
    {
        MsgType = "text";
    }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string MsgId { get; set; }
}
```

There are several classes inherit from the baseclass model also and now I only show one here.

And here is the method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Produces("application/xml")]
public async Task<IActionResult> mp([FromBody]BaseClass XmlData)
{
    BaseClass ReturnXmlData = null;
    var a = XmlData.GetType();            
    return Ok(ReturnXmlData);
}
```

The remote server will post a request contains XML to my server. Now the incoming variable `XmlData` only gets the value and type of the baseclass.

I need to get the true value and type, and then return different XML by the incoming type and value.

How can I solve this? Thank you.

---

This is one of the incoming XML, matches the TextMsg model above:

```
<xml> 
<ToUserName>123</ToUserName>
<FromUserName>456</FromUserName>
<CreateTime>1348831860</CreateTime>
<MsgType>text</MsgType>
<Content>this is a test</Content>
<MsgId>1234567890123456</MsgId>
</xml>
```

Comment: Does the incoming xml contain some attributes telling us the type? Or we can understand what the type is only by properties count/names within xml? Could please add few examples of possible incoming xml?

Comment: @Alexander for example:<xml>
  <ToUserName>123</ToUserName>
  <FromUserName>456</FromUserName>
  <CreateTime>1348831860</CreateTime>
  <MsgType>text</MsgType>
  <Content>this is a test</Content>
  <MsgId>1234567890123456</MsgId>
</xml>

Comment: @Alexander Here is another example:<xml>
  <ToUserName>123</ToUserName>
  <FromUserName>456</FromUserName>
  <CreateTime>1348831860</CreateTime>
  <MsgType>image</MsgType>
  <PicUrl>this is a url</PicUrl>
  <MediaId>media_id</MediaId>
  <MsgId>1234567890123456</MsgId>
</xml>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom model binder for this

```
public class XmlBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            await bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            XElement root = XElement.Load(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            string messageType = root.Element("MsgType").Value;
            Type xmlType = GetTypeFromMessage(messageType);
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(xmlType);
            var model = serializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        }
        catch
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
        }
    }

    private Type GetTypeFromMessage(string msgType)
    {
        switch (msgType)
        {
            case "text":
                return typeof(TextMsg);
            case "image":
                return typeof(ImageMsg);
            //... other cases
            default:
                return typeof(BaseClass);
        }
    }
}
```

Apply this model binder for `BaseClass`

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(XmlBinder))]
public class BaseXml
```

Comment: The only downside of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58075582/7775908) is that the custom input formatter will be applied for every xml request that may not be related bo `BaseClass` at all.

Comment: This is not only the best demo for model binding but also the easier way I have ever seem! I love it very much!

Comment: I prefer this way more for it is only applied for a class but not every xml request. As we know there are so many unexpected types of XML incoming of the project in the future. This way is more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

You could write you own `XmlSerializerInputFormatter` based on its [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/8b861ea7d717eb09673d4ca648dc96ebe36fe425/src/Mvc/Mvc.Formatters.Xml/src/XmlSerializerInputFormatter.cs),for example:

```
[Obsolete]
public class XmlCreationConverter: XmlSerializerInputFormatter
{    
    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(
       InputFormatterContext context,
       Encoding encoding)
    {
        XElement xml = null;
        Type type = typeof(BaseClass);
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        context.HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
        {
            reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            request.Body.Position = 0; // rewind
            xml = XElement.Parse(text);

            //your logic to return the right type
            if (xml.Element("MsgType").Value == "text")
            {
                type = typeof(TextMsg);
            }
            else if(...)
            {
                type = ...
            }
            else
            {
            }

            using (XmlReader xmlReader = CreateXmlReader(request.Body, encoding))
            {
                var serializer = GetCachedSerializer(type);
                var deserializedObject = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
                return InputFormatterResult.Success(deserializedObject);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc(options=> options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlCreationConverter()))
                .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[Produces("application/xml")]
public async Task<IActionResult> mp([FromBody]BaseClass XmlData)
```

**Update:**
For asp.net core 3.0, change code to below:

```
public class XmlCreationConverter : XmlSerializerInputFormatter
{
    private readonly MvcOptions _options;
    public XmlCreationConverter(MvcOptions options) : base(options)

    {
        _options = options;
    }
    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(
       InputFormatterContext context,
       Encoding encoding)
    {
        XElement xml = null;
        Type type = typeof(BaseClass);
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        context.HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();

       //for model type is Baseclass
       if (context.ModelType == typeof(BaseClass))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
            {
                var text = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                request.Body.Position = 0;
                xml = XElement.Parse(text);
                if (xml.Element("MsgType").Value == "text")
                {
                    type = typeof(TextMsg);
                }

                using (XmlReader xmlReader = CreateXmlReader(request.Body, encoding))
                {
                    var serializer = GetCachedSerializer(type);
                    var deserializedObject = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
                    return InputFormatterResult.Success(deserializedObject);
                }
            }
        }
        else if(context.ModelType == ...)
        else
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
            {
                var text = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                request.Body.Position = 0;
                using (var xmlReader = CreateXmlReader(request.Body, encoding))
                {
                    var modelType = GetSerializableType(context.ModelType);

                    var serializer = GetCachedSerializer(modelType);

                    var deserializedObject = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);

                    // Unwrap only if the original type was wrapped.
                    if (type != context.ModelType)
                    {
                        if (deserializedObject is IUnwrappable unwrappable)
                        {
                            deserializedObject = unwrappable.Unwrap(declaredType: context.ModelType);
                        }
                    }

                    return InputFormatterResult.Success(deserializedObject);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddMvc(options => options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlCreationConverter(options)))
                .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

Comment: I followed your code by creating a new .cs file named XmlCreationConverter and added whole codes. Meanwhile, the visual studio reports two errors. One is "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'options' of 'XmlSerializerInputFormatter.XmlSerializerInputFormatter(MVCOptions)" about the XmlCreationConverter class.

Comment: The other is "'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'EnableRewind' and no accessible extension method 'EnableRewind' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found" about "context.HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind();". I searched in google and someone said I should install a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http NuGet package to solve it. I tried but no works.

Comment: Many people let me create a custom modelbinder. I have read many articles about it but still can hardly get to know about it. It seems your way is much easier and different from the custom modelbinder way. Would you please tell me what is the difference between these two ways. Thank you.

Comment: Moreover, the version of .net core I am using is .net core 3.0

Comment: @102425074 You need to have a reference `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal`.What I do is also custom binding for [input formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.0#input-formatters).Oh,I test it in asp.net core 2.2

Comment: I found the way as you said by adding a reference 'using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal' and it still no works. After then I found someone said that the EnableRewind has change into EnableBuffering in .net core 3.0. However I am not sure about this.

Comment: @102425074 I try it in asp.net core 3.0,see my updated code

Comment: Now it works. I am a .net core beginner. I always think it is easy to do this.

I have paid a whole day on it, by learning custom model binding via Microsoft official tutorial but finally get nothing.

On the one hand, I only know your way is to rewrite the method of XML input. On the other hand, I can hardly get to know the source code for XmlSerializerInputFormatter.

I want to learn more about it while I don't know where to start.

Almost nothing about this in google yet except only the tutorial of Microsoft official.

Comment: There is one more question. This way needs to add InputFormatters in the services. That means the ReadRequestBodyAsync works in the whole project.

If there are different XML ReadRequestBody requirements in my project, how can I solve it?

In my opinion, maybe I only can write a method to serialize the XML by myself, right?

Comment: @102425074 You could add if/else clause to judege the type of `context.ModelType`,and then give different types  different methods.At last,add a default method for other models you do not have requirements on.I update code.Anyway, the above model binding seems to be more flexible,I am glad you have resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to create a custom modelbinder, which is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow. With the default modelbinder, the type of the param will be instantiated, and anything from the body that doesn't fit on that type will simply be discarded. As a result, you'll end up with literally an instance of `BaseClass`, with no ability to cast it to any more specific derived type.

The only out of the box option is to literally bind to the class type you want (i.e. the derived type, not the base type) and have alternate endpoints for each derived typed. Alternatively, you can create a superclass that encompasses all properties from all the various derived types in order to bind to, and then depending on which properties get filled, you can manually map to the appropriate derived class.

Comment: Someone tell me to use the Polymorphic model binding. As you see, my model is so simple, I don't think I should use these so complex codes yet.

Comment: This is the easy way. Creating your own modelbinder to handle this would be complex.

Comment: The last way by creating a superclass that encompasses all properties is easy. However, I doubt if it will lower the performance of the API.