# How to support inheritance as formbody in controller at .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I have parent class like this

```
  public class BaseSchema
    {
        public DataType Type { set; get; }
        public string Label { set; get; }
        public bool Visibility { set; get; }
        public string Hint { set; get; }
    }
```

and the child class is

```
  public class SingleLineSchema : BaseSchema
    {
        public string CustomFieldExample { set; get; }
    }
```

In request dto, I used BaseSchema (Parent). My expectation is able to receive both parent and child json.

```
  public class UpdateFormSchemaRequestDto
    {
        public string Id { set; get; }
        public BaseSchema FormSchema { set; get; }
    }
```

And my controller is

```
[HttpPut]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateSchema(UpdateFormSchemaRequestDto updateFormSchemaRequestDto)
        {
            var response = await _formSchemaService.UpdateFormSchema(updateFormSchemaRequestDto);
            return Response.Create(response);
        }
```

My expectation is able to receive both parent and child json.But i only able to get parent jsons only. If child json was given, it automatically converts to parent object. So how to support inheritance or is it any better way to handle?

Comment: What is in the request? (Use something like fiddler to capture what is sent in the request: don't rely on the request object.)

Comment: In your request DTO `UpdateFormSchemaRequestDto`, why are you using the parent `BaseSchema` and not the child `SingleLineSchema` ? It will never fill-in the child data because you are not asking for it.

Comment: Hi @Junior and @Richard, There are more childs for parent object (`BaseSchema`). So i putted parent class as data type. We can assign child object to parent like this  `BaseSchema bs= new BaseSchema()` &  `BaseSchema bs= new SingleLineSchema()` & `BaseSchema bs= new MoreChildSchema()` . So i am assuming we can assign all childs to parent.

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of model binding?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58063437/how-can-i-get-the-right-type-from-a-frombody-model-which-is-inherits